# Injecting List of Prototypes into Singleton bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Need some help in spring here.
In our project we use XML and annotation configurations (Spring 4.1)
Recently I've faced the following task:

I have a list of beans of scope **prototype**, all of them implement the same interface.

In addition I have one singleton bean that has `execute` method. Inside the method the bean should access the list of those prototype beans.

Every time the 'execute' method gets executed I would like to get the access to the different instances of those prototype beans).
In singleton I don't have the whole list of beans known in advance, so I just `@Autowire` the whole collection so that every bean implementation known in the application context will be loaded.

```
interface SomeInterface {

}


class PrototypeBean1 implements SomeInterface {
  ...
}

class PrototypeBean2 implements SomeInterface {
  ...
}


class MySingletonBean {

   @Autowire (????)
   List<SomeInterface> allPrototypeBeansLoadedIntoTheApplicationContext;

   public void execute() {
      // this one is called many times,
      // so I would like to get different lists of    
      //"allPrototypeBeansLoadedIntoTheApplicationContext"
      // with different actuals bean upon every invocation
      // how do I achieve this???
   }

}
```

So my question is: **What is the most clean way to achieve this?** Ideally I would like to get a solution totally decoupled from spring interfaces (like injecting ApplicationContext/BeanFactory stuff)
I don't mind to use Aop here (performance is not that critical), but I can't really wrap my head around a clean spring solution. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to achieve similar goal with Spring and after reading Spring docs using either [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) or [method injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s03.html#beans-factory-method-injection) (with [@Lookup](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html)) came up and looked promising. 
However after tried both approach results turned out to be frustrating. Neither way supports returning beans in List.  And I got this exception:

> No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available

Apparently Spring treated the return type as a regular Object.

So eventually my solution became creating a new object to wrap the list as return type.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ProcessorList
{
    private List<Processor> processors;

    public ProcessorList(List<Processor> processors)
    {
        this.processors = processors;
    }

    public List<Processor> getProcessors()
    {
        return processors;
    }

    public void setProcessors(List<ChangeSetProcessor> processors)
    {
        this.processors = processors;
    }
}
```

then create a Factory class for the List Object:

```
@Component
public interface ProcessorFactory
{
    ProcessorList getProcessorList();
}
```

Then use ServiceLocatorFactoryBean to register the factory:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public FactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean()
    {
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(ProcessorFactory.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

Finally implement the interface and make sure mark them all with @Scope("prototype")

Now you'll get new instance each time you use the factory method!

It's similar to use method injection if you prefer.